# what is a great progress query tool

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, 4gl

I am new to Progress. Previously I worked with Oracle, MSSQL and MYSQL. What is a great progress query tool, free or paid? I want to be able to write simple SQL queries.
In oracle i am using Toad,Pl/sql developer tool to connect oracle. Any thing in Progress 4gl?

Thank you

Comment: Asking for such recommendations is off topic on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score -1):

You can use any random SQL query tool that you like if the SQL engine has been exposed by the DBA.  You just need login credentials and permissions just as you would for any SQL db.

Since you want to write SQL queries you should be looking for SQL access not 4GL tools.  There is a very, very limited SQL subset embedded within the 4GL but that was created in the 80s and is little more than a marketing gimmick.  For anything but trivial SQL you want to use the SQL-92 engine.  Which means the DBA needs to have started a SQL broker, provided a port # for you and has granted appropriate permissions.